# Objective - c How to get Data from popToRootViewController class, I have Text field in that class I want that textfield text when screen is popped

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `UITextField` in that class I want that textfield text when screen is popped

I have try property to access value of textfield but it returns nil

```
AddItem *item = [AddItem viewController];

NSLog(@"%@",item.txtField.text);
```

Add Item is My Class which will be shown on click 
it shows nil

Comment: What does `[AddItem viewController]`? Does this create a new object?

Comment: Yes `[AddItem viewController ] is method which create  new object of AddItem Class with Nib .of view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a Notification with object= content of your textfield, before calling popToRoot. Then in the root viewcontroller, add it as observer to this notification.

Another method: set a reference to your root controller in your 3rd controller. Add a method 'closeToMe:' that call PopToRoot in the root controller. Then, from 3rd controller, when you want to 'pop-to-root', you call [referenceToA closeToMe:] with the content of your textfield.

Here is the snip code:

```
RootViewController:

//to be simple, declare this in header to facilite access to this function
-(void)closeToMe:(NSString*)newContent {
     //do your work with newContent

    //then, call poptoRoot (in main thread)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),nil, {
        //navigation.PopToCOntroller(self)
    });
}


3rdController):

@property (nonatomic) RootViewController; //set it when you show the pop-up from RootViewController

-(IBAction)close:(id)sender {
    if (self.controller && [self.controller respondsTo:@sel(closeToMe:)]) {
        [self.controller closeToMe:myTextField.text];
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any other method to do it  ?

Comment: I updated my answer with some code for another solution